# How to store a mongoose result into a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am unable to store my mongoose.js results(it's an object). Below is my code.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/templatesDB', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

```
const templateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
  title: String,
    aside: Array,
  downloads: Number,
  type: String,
    meta: {
        title: String,
        desc: String,
        imgURL: String,
        imgAlt: String,
        URL: String,
        keywords: Array
    },
    template: {
        name: String,
        img: String,
        imgAlt: String,
    },
    developer: {
        name: String,
        href: String,
    },
    links: {
        download: String,
        preview: String,
        github: String,
    },
    technologies: Array,
    tags: Array,
    about: {
        desc: String,
        usage: Array
    }
});
```

```
let json = {
        _id: 1,
        title: "Mansionify",
        downloads: 0,
        type: "landing",
        meta: {
            title: "Mansionify Landing Page",
            desc: "Real Estate Landing Page By Abraham Ebijuni",
            imgURL: "/img/png/mansionify.png",
            imgAlt: "Mansionify Preview Image",
            URL: "/templates/mansionify",
            keywords: ["Mansionify", "Landing Page", "Real", "Estate", "Real Estate", "Page", "Housing", "Big House", "Mansion", "Mansions", "html", "html5", "css", "tailwindcss", "tailwind", "npm", "Abraham", "Ebijuni", "Abraham Ebijuni"]
        },
        template: {
            name: "Mansionify",
            img: "/img/png/mansionify.png",
            imgAlt: "Mansionify Preview Image",
        },
        developer: {
            name: "Abraham Ebijuni",
            href: "https://github.com/abrahamebij",
        },
        links: {
            download: "/templates/manionify/download",
            preview: "https://github.com/abrahamebij/bootstrap-bootcamp",
            github: "https://github.com/abrahamebij/my-calculator",
        },
        technologies: ["html", "tailwindcss", "npm"],
        tags: ["Landing Page", "Real Estate", "Housing"],
        about: {
            desc: "Mansionify is a basic Tailwind 3.0 Real Estate landing page that you can download and use out of the box without having to change any file paths. Everything you need to start development on this Tailwind project is here, which includes the core Tailwind CSS and JS bundle along with OwlCalrousel Library.",
            usage: ["cd 'Project\ Folder'", "npm install", "npx tailwindcss --watch", "And you are good to go"]
        },
        aside: [
            {
                img: "/img/png/templatify.png",
                imgAlt: "Templatify Overview",
                title: "Templatify",
                desc: "A landing page for templates",
                downloads: 2,
                link: "/donate",
            },
            {
                img: "/img/png/w3schools.png",
                imgAlt: "W3shools Overview",
                title: "W3schools",
                desc: "A website page for web learning",
                downloads: 2,
                link: "/contact",
            },
            {
                img: "/img/png/mansionify.png",
                imgAlt: "Mansionify Overview",
                title: "Mansionify",
                desc: "A landing page for real estate",
                downloads: 2,
                link: "/mansionify",
            },
        ]
    };
```

**Saving the object**

```
const Template = mongoose.model("Template", templateSchema);

const template = new Template(json)
template.save();
```

**Now when I try to access it using the console.log() method, it works**

```
Template.findOne(function (err, temp) {
  console.log(err ? err : temp); // returns the object
});
```

**If I try to store it into a variable**

```
const data = Template.find(function (err, temp) {
  return (err ? err : temp);
});

console.log(data)
```

It just returns this whole stuff

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionStack: null,
  mongooseCollection: Collection {
    collection: null,
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    modelName: 'Template',
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      autoIndex: true,
      autoCreate: true,
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
      capped: false,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'templates',
    collectionName: 'templates',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: {},
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 2,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: false,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _queue: [],
      _listening: false,
      _connectionString: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/templatesDB',
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise]
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: true,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { Template },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: {
      _id: [Function: Number],
      title: [Function: String],
      aside: [Function: Array],
      downloads: [Function: Number],
      type: [Function: String],
      meta: [Object],
      template: [Object],
      developer: [Object],
      links: [Object],
      technologies: [Function: Array],
      tags: [Function: Array],
      about: [Object]
    },
    paths: {
      _id: [SchemaNumber],
      title: [SchemaString],
      aside: [SchemaArray],
      downloads: [SchemaNumber],
      type: [SchemaString],
      'meta.title': [SchemaString],
      'meta.desc': [SchemaString],
      'meta.imgURL': [SchemaString],
      'meta.imgAlt': [SchemaString],
      'meta.URL': [SchemaString],
      'meta.keywords': [SchemaArray],
      'template.name': [SchemaString],
      'template.img': [SchemaString],
      'template.imgAlt': [SchemaString],
      'developer.name': [SchemaString],
      'developer.href': [SchemaString],
      'links.download': [SchemaString],
      'links.preview': [SchemaString],
      'links.github': [SchemaString],
      technologies: [SchemaArray],
      tags: [SchemaArray],
      'about.desc': [SchemaString],
      'about.usage': [SchemaArray],
      __v: [SchemaNumber]
    },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {
      'aside.$': [Mixed],
      'meta.keywords.$': [Mixed],
      'technologies.$': [Mixed],
      'tags.$': [Mixed],
      'about.usage.$': [Mixed]
    },
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {
      meta: true,
      template: true,
      developer: true,
      links: true,
      about: true
    },
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: {
      _id: [Function: Number],
      title: [Function: String],
      aside: [Function: Array],
      downloads: [Function: Number],
      type: [Function: String],
      meta: [Object],
      template: [Object],
      developer: [Object],
      links: [Object],
      technologies: [Function: Array],
      tags: [Function: Array],
      about: [Object],
      __v: [Function: Number],
      id: [VirtualType]
    },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 1,
    mapPaths: [],
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: {},
    options: {
      typeKey: 'type',
      id: true,
      _id: true,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      optimisticConcurrency: false,
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      strictQuery: true,
      strict: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
    _requiredpaths: [],
    _indexedpaths: []
  },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: Collection {
      collection: null,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      modelName: 'Template',
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'templates',
      collectionName: 'templates',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: true,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'templates'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true
}
```

How can I save that particular object into a variable? Thanks for reading.

Comment: `... function(err, temp) { ...` - the variable `temp` has the result value.

Comment: It only works for console.log(). I want to save it to a variable.

Comment: The operation for the MongoDB is an asynchronous one, you should always use some async patterns to wait until you get the answer from the mongodb using mongoose. There is an interface when mongoose is returning the data you have requested that it is `_doc` while you are awaiting and the promise has been resolved you will get the `document = _doc` that you have asked for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the result of query in a variable that outside of your callback function you have to `await` the query:

```js
let data;
try {
  data = await Template.find();
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

console.log(data);
```

Make sure you have `async` keyword in front of the function you write the query.